# How can I target windows 7 with a Visual Studio 2022 installation project?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Framework 4.8 on a desktop VB application. The VS2019 installation project (which allows works with Windows 7, 10, and 11) became "incompatible" with a VS2022 upgrade. The dropdown for minimum Windows target only goes as low as Windows 10.

Comment: as long as you have a dotnet version that is compable, you can select Windows 7 in the Project propertoes. you still need to remeber that windows 7 is out of support in most cases. Upgradiung is difficultm as it  makes a lot of errors. what helps is making a empty project and import file for file. so that the project has all the right configuration.